# Window decoration in SDL2 missing

Tags: c, sdl, gnome, window-decoration

I am trying to create a window in SDL2 using the SDL_CreateWindow() function.
The window created by the SDL_CreateWindow() function in my code has no window decorations.
I am using GNOME Mutter.

Running the output of the code below from my terminal creates a blank window with no title bar

[image]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "Window",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            640,
            480,
            0
            );
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want the window created by SDL_CreateWindow() to have a title bar and an exit button

Comment: Try actually running an event loop. Maybe it'll fix itself.

Comment: Originally I was using an Event Loop and I was getting this same behaviour, I also tried using a for loop i.e. `for (int i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFFFF; i++)` and the window had no decorations.

Comment: Can you show us the code with an event loop?

Comment: Where did you get your SDL2? Did you build it yourself?

Comment: The code I am using won't fit in this comment box, but I have tried running the code from [https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php](LazyFoo's first SDL tutorial) and I got the same behaviour.  
I got my SDL using the APT package libsdl2-dev i.e. `sudo apt install -y libsdl2-dev`

Comment: That code also doesn't have an event loop. Can you edit your question and add your code that has one?

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong tutorial.

I have tried the code from https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php and the window still has no decoration

Comment: Works for me on Xubuntu... As the next step I suggest creating a minimal VM with the same distribution as you use, and trying it there. If it works, then you can start figuring out what's different about your system.

Comment: A random guess: maybe the window title bar is too high up to be visible? Try passing something like `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED` instead of `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED`.

Comment: After trying your suggestion of running a VM, I have found that running the code in an Ubuntu 20.04 VM (VirtualBox) gives me the window decoration.

Comment: Some configuration problem then? Does `printenv` print anything that starts with `SDL`?

Comment: I ran `printenv | grep SDL` and got nothing

Comment: If you're using Gnome with Wayland is your SDL version at or past [`ac904b8e95`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/pull/4068) and is [`libdecor`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jadahl/libdecor) installed?

Comment: @genpfault My SDL version is [2.0.14: Hirsute Hippo released in January](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/+source/libsdl2)

I ran `dpkg -l libdecor` and the output said I had no packages named libdecor